# Safari doesn't understand my Content-Security-Policy headers

Tags: nginx, websocket, safari, http-headers, content-security-policy

Every other browser understands when I say:

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' unsafe-inline; connect-src wss://mysite.com;
```

In my headers. But Safari says:

> Refused to connect to wws://mysite because it doesn't not appear in
>   the connect-src directive in Content Security Policy. [Error]
>   SecurityError (DOM Exception 18): The operation is insecure.
>   (anonymous function) (myjavascripturl.js)

Why does Safari not understand my Content-Security-Policy headers?

Comment: I started a bounty because I can't accept the first answer. I want to make it possible for all stages of my software. The first answer would resolve it for only one stage

Answer (score 4):

In the policy you have provided there are no single quotes around unsafe-inline which are required. Change this:

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' unsafe-inline; connect-src wss://mysite.com;
```

To this:

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src wss://mysite.com;
-------------------------------------------------------------------------^-------------^
```

That could be affecting the parsing of the policy.

The other concern is in the error message you provided.

```
Refused to connect to wws://mysite
-----------------------^
```

Do you have a typo somewhere in your code, should this be wss?